# Android: Update 2 Fragments Simultaneously

Tags: android

I have 2 fragments in my application, one has a timer (Frag A) and the other (Frag B) renders an image on the canvas. My problem is that I'm using countdowntimer in Frag A and Frag B only does the rendering steps in-sync with Frag A. My question is, is it possible to draw on UI asynchronously for 2 fragments? Or do both fragments run on the same UI thread? If so how would I go about rendering on both fragments without affecting one another?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Does Frag A also draw in each step?